# WebView crashes app when back button is pressed, Xamarin.forms, android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

mine app crashes while pressing back button.
I have product layout, where everything is loaded, with product description which is in html format, so I'm using WebView. When I go in product and fast tap back button, app crashes with error "cannot access a disposed object, Android.Webkit.WebView".

```
var fullDesc = new ProductPageWebView() { HeightRequest = 20 };
        fullDesc.Margin = -8;
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        htmlSource.Html = product.FullDescription;

        fullDesc.Source = htmlSource;
        overviewContent.Children.Add(fullDesc);

        innerGrid.Children.Add(overviewContent, 0, 3, 7, 8);
```

I've commented fullDesc.Source = htmlSource; and nothing is crashing, so problem is there. How to fix it?
It is crashing only on android.
It is xamarin app
.net standard 2.0

ProductPageWebView inherits from WebView

Comment: Can you share your sample so that I can test it on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was there, in CustomRenderer file:

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100); // wait here till content is rendered 
wv.HeightRequest = (double)webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height;
```

First line should be deleted, it shouldn't wait.